# loading html via js, the css in the html does not work. bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

Im using bootstrap 5.
In index.html, im inserting the nav.html via js.
The problem is, the navbar CSS doesnt work when loaded via js. But does work if i copy the nav.html code itself into index.html.

ie. the main.css colors for `navbar` and `navbar-brand` are not showing when nav.html is loaded into index, but the colors do show when the nav code is in index, and not using the js loading.

The nav.html gets copied into many pages, thats what i want, but there is no styling. why?

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">

            <!--Navigation bar-->
            <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
            <script>
              $(function(){ $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html") });
            </script>
            <!--end of Navigation bar-->

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### nav.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">My Co.</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="legal.html">Legal</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

### main.css

```
.navbar {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}
.navbar-brand {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: I think nav.html is incomplete. It has no head or body tag and <HTML> tag is also missing.

Answer (score 0):

In the Network tab of the developer console, what is the status code ?  It could just be a wrong path of your html file.

Without self-invoking expression it should work:

```
$("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
```

Or if you still want a self-invoking expression:

```
(function(){ $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html"); })();
```

Answer (score 0):

stupid me. its the order of my css.

ie.

from `class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"`

to `class="navbar navbar-expand-lg"`

the nav css displays correctly with the colors in main.css

Comment: .bg-light was overriding your css rules.